# r finding members in only one of the two groups and in both the groups

Tags: r, dplyr

If this is my data

```
Number        Group  Length    
4432          1      NA        
4432          2      2.34      
4564          1      5.89      
4389          1      NA        
6578          2      3.12       
4389          2      NA            
4355          1      4.11      
4355          2      6.15       
4689          1      6.22      
4689          1      NA
```

I am trying to find Ship `Numbers` that are only in either Group1 or Group2 and Ship `Numbers`that are in both Group1 and Group2.

```
Number        Group  Length    Results
4432          1      NA        Both 1 &2
4432          2      2.34      Both 1 &2
4564          1      5.89      1
4389          1      NA        1
6578          2      3.12      2 
4389          2      NA        2    
4355          1      4.11      Both 1 & 2
4355          2      6.15      Both 1 & 2 
4689          1      6.22      1
4689          1      NA        1
```

I can do this using for loops and subsets, i am interested in a dplyr or other approaches to creating the `Results` column. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `n_distinct` to do a check on the number of unique 'Group' and paste the `unique` 'Group' with the prefix 'Both'

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(Number)) %>%
   mutate(Results = case_when(n_distinct(Group) >1 ~ 
                      str_c("Both ", str_c(unique(Group), collapse=" & ")),
     TRUE ~ as.character(unique(Group)))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   Number Group Length Results   
#    <int> <int>  <dbl> <chr>     
# 1   4432     1  NA    Both 1 & 2
# 2   4432     2   2.34 Both 1 & 2
# 3   4564     1   5.89 1         
# 4   4389     1  NA    1         
# 5   6578     2   3.12 2         
# 6   4389     2  NA    2         
# 7   4355     1   4.11 Both 1 & 2
# 8   4355     2   6.15 Both 1 & 2
# 9   4689     1   6.22 1         
#10   4689     1  NA    1
```

If 'Both' is not required

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(Number)) %>%
   mutate(Results = str_c(unique(Group), collapse=" & ")) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Number = c(4432L, 4432L, 4564L, 4389L, 6578L, 
4389L, 4355L, 4355L, 4689L, 4689L), Group = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Length = c(NA, 2.34, 5.89, NA, 3.12, 
NA, 4.11, 6.15, 6.22, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: your initial solution worked. I did not try the latest version. i will try that as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Science11 My initial solution was based on grouping with Number as such, but when I checked your expected, I find that you are grouping only based on adjacent elements that are same,  So, I changed that to `rleid(Number)`

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Row-wise concatenate the Group vector by the number separating it with an " & "

aggregated_df <- aggregate(list(Results = df$Group), list(Number = df$Number), paste0, collapse = " & ")

# Preserve unique elements (removing the ampersand if elements are duplicated): 

aggregated_df$Results <- sapply(strsplit(aggregated_df$Results, " & "),

                               function(x){paste0(unique(x), collapse = " & ")})

# If the string contains an ampersand concatenate both infront of the grouping string: 

aggregated_df$Group <- ifelse(grepl(" & ", aggregated_df$Results), paste0("Both ", aggregated_df$Results),
                              aggregated_df$Results)

# Merge the two dataframes together: 

df <- merge(df, aggregated_df, by = "Number", all.x = T, sort = F)
```

Base R Solution 2 (split, apply, combine):

```
# Split dataframe by number, apply group concatenation function, combine as data.frame:

df2 <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$Number), function(x){

        res <- paste0(unique(x$Group), collapse = " & ")

        x$Result <- ifelse(grepl(" & ", res), paste0("Both ", res), res)

        x

      }

    )

  ),

 row.names = NULL

)

# Reorder the new dataframe using the old df order: 

df2 <- df2[order(df$Number),]
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    Number = c(
      4432L,
      4432L,
      4564L,
      4389L,
      6578L,
      4389L,
      4355L,
      4355L,
      4689L,
      4689L
    ),
    Group = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
              2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L),
    Length = c(NA, 2.34, 5.89, NA, 3.12,
               NA, 4.11, 6.15, 6.22, NA)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-10L)
)
```